# cannot install iOS 7.1 simulator for Xcode 6 (weird file mounting error)

Tags: macos, xcode, xcode-simulator

I have `XCode 5.1` working without problems with iOS 7.1 simulators until yesterday when I upgraded to `Xcode 6`, the installation was completed successfully, but whenever I try to download and install iOS 7.1 simulator from `Preferences -> Downloads`, it gives me this weird message:

```
Could not download and install iOS 7.1 Simulator. Failed to mount  file:///Users/myusername/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/Xcode.SDK.iPhoneSimulator.7.1-7.1.dmg at file:///var/folders/f8/4wmmmwj17_96v9jp7h1f4gqc0000gn/T/attached-image-85355a6e6ed97fd1899b8ef3a6052181e745b5fb/: image not recognized
```

I searched for such error but couldn't find any clue to solve it.
I completely removed `XCode` using `CleanMyMac 2` app, restarted the machine, re-installed `Xcode` from `MAC App Store`, the installation was successful, restarted the machine again, and then tried to install iOS 7.1 simulator but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

1. Quit Xcode (<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>).
2. Delete the `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode` folder.
3. Reopen Xcode.